# W3.org validation stuck on one inline javascript attribute, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with the following code for a specific element:

```
<textarea id="textToTranslate" onfinishinput="dothis()" rows="5"></textarea>
```

onfinishinput waits for the user input and check if he is stopped. If he stop typing, the function dothis is called throught $('#waitUserInput').live() function.
The tricky part of my question is, how to change the above line to be completely jQuery.

The jQuery dat correspont to the dothis() function is the following:

```
// Detect if user input stops
$('#waitUserInput').live("keyup", function(e)
{
    startTypingTimer($(e.target));
});


var typingTimeout;
function startTypingTimer(input_field)
{
    if (typingTimeout != undefined)
        clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    typingTimeout = setTimeout( function()
    {
        eval(input_field.attr("onfinishinput"));
    }
    , 250);
}
```

Javascript dothis() function:

```
function dothis(){
   // Ajax call when called
{
```

Now, when I go to http://validator.w3.org, I have one error, and yes it is about the above code:
**Attribute onfinishinput not allowed on element textarea at this point.**

```
<textarea id="textToTranslate" onfinishinput="dothis()" rows="5"></textarea>
```

The question is, is it possible to turn the onfinishinput javascript attribute out of the textarea, but so that is is functioning the same?

I know it is a little complex, but I hope someone can help.

Comment: Where is the attribute coming from? I have not seen it in any specification... That said, you can probably do `$('#textToTranslate").bind('finishinput', dothis)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just change:

```
eval(input_field.attr("onfinishinput"));
```

To:

```
dothis();
```

And then remove the 'onfinishinput' attribute from your textarea?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such attribute called 'onfinishinput' for the TEXTAREA so the validator is correct.  Including it does in fact violate the standard.

It appears that what you are trying to do is to be able to have a different handler for each TEXTAREA on a page so that you can take different actions.  If that is the case, why not just have your jQuery call dothis() unconditionally and pass the control that fired the event as a parameter?

You could then put control-specific handling in your dothis() function based on the ID of the passed control.

Answer (score 1):

How about binding the event differently and removing the attribute:

```
$('#textToTranslate').bind('onfinishinput', dothis');
```

You'd then need to trigger the event using jQuery's trigger (see http://api.jquery.com/bind/)